# Alternating page numbering using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I have a question regarding alternating page numbering using `fancyhdr`.

At the moment I'm using

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=black,
citecolor = black,
urlcolor=blue,
pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\input{Abstract}
\input{Acknowledgements}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage 
...
\end{document}
```

This results in both my section and my number ends up on the write side. However my thesis is now going into print and I want both my header and my page number to be alternating between the left and the right side. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an short compilable TeX code? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch Thank you, I edited the question now, hopefully it's more understandable.

Comment: Document class?

Comment: I only used \documentclass{article}, but when I changed to \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article} and added 

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\rhead` and `\rfoot`, try

```
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

If you want the numbers on the other sides, replace `LE,RO` with `LO,RE`.

See https://texblog.org/2007/11/07/headerfooter-in-latex-with-fancyhdr/ for more details.

Comment: That worked! I also had to add more specifics to my \documentclass: \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

Comment: Ah yes. Article and Report defaults to single-sided, and Book defaults to two-sided. (Incidentally that's why I asked about document class in my comment above.)